# android - OkHttp: How can I add a whole map into a single key-value parameter?

Tags: android, okhttp

The screenshot in the link below shows the parameters which I will put to a POST request using Alamofire in Swift.

[image]

My question is: How can I do the same thing using OkHttp in Kotlin? How can I add "data" as a key and a whole map of user details as a single value?

I have googled around for a while and everything just ends up adding each key-value pair into a FormBody.

This is my first time asking a question on StackOverflow so if there is anything wrong with my language, please kindly tell me so that I can fix it.

Thank you

Comment: Have a try to Retrofit https://square.github.io/retrofit/

Answer (score 0):

Within Retrofit, you can pass an Object as your `@Body` tag.

For example, you can add a new user with something like this.

```
@POST("users")
fun add(@Body user: User): Observable<User>
```

It will use `GSON` to serialize your data for you, and will make json that matches your model.